# Problems using execv and shell exec

Tags: c++, linux, macos, shell

I'm trying to fire a process from C++ using the execv system call. It works perfectly until I tried to source the user environment before launching my process by invoking a non interactive shell.

What I basically change is that my command (for this example, I used a test.bin file that dumps the argv[] array) now is prefixed with: /bin/sh -l -c "exec ./testbin testargv1 testargv2"

When I launch the command from another shell, i get this:

0: ./testbin
1: ./testargv1
2: ./testargv2

while, when I launch it through execve in the c++ programs , i get:

0: /bin/sh
1: -l
2: -c
3: exec ./testbin testargv1 testargv2

from within c, I'm simply doing the following:

```
char* exe = "/bin/sh";
char** params = { "/bin/sh","-l","-c","exec ./testbin testargv1 testargv2",0 };

execv(exe,params);
```

It's like when launched from execve , the shell is not re-arranging the argv before forking itself.

Does someone has any hints ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are showing us the right code? To me it looks like you are doing something like this:

```
char* exe = "./testbin";
char** params = { "/bin/sh","-l","-c","exec ./testbin testargv1 testargv2",0 };
execv(exe,params);
```

Typically you would drop the `exe` variable and call `execv` like this:

```
execv(params[0], params);
```

Comment: not exactly this but the problem was indeed in my non pseudo-code that was passing the wrong executable name